# List of filter item SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, closures, swiftui

I'm try to list the result of a filter item received via a function with an escape closure.
If I try the function in Playground it works, so now Im try to use it in SwiftUI list.

But Xcode give me warning...

Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type '_'

here my search function

```
 typealias exit = (([AirportModel]) -> ())

    func filter (valoreSearhed: String, arrayTosearh: [AirportModel],  closure: @escaping exit)  {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let aeroportoFiltrato  = arrayTosearh.filter { $0.aptICAO.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(valoreSearhed) }
            closure(aeroportoFiltrato)
        }
    }
```

and here my list

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //            fakebar
            SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)

            List {
                dm.filter(valoreSearhed: searchTerm, arrayTosearh: dm.airportVector) { (item) in
                    ForEach(item) { valore in
                        Text(valore.aptICAO)
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep all the `View` elements in the same thread, without dispatch.

So change your filter function to:

```swift
func filter (valoreSearhed: String, arrayTosearh: [AirportModel]) -> [AirportModel]  {
    return arrayTosearh.filter { $0.aptICAO.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(valoreSearhed) }
}
```

Then your `View` code to:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(dm.filter(valoreSearhed: searchTerm, arrayTosearh: dm.airportVector)) { valore in
        Text(valore.aptICAO)
    }
}
```

**Edit**

To have the filtering happen in another thread, keep a `@State` var with the results:

```swift
@State var filteredAirports: [AirportModel] = []

init() {
    dm.filter( ... ) {
        self.filteredAirports = $0
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(filteredAirports) { valore in
                Text(valore.aptICAO)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood... problem is I need to do the search in a different thread because the vector where I’m searching is very big

Comment: So you need a `@State` var with the result. Then you can have it update the view as the results arrive.

Comment: See addition to the answer above.

Comment: I changed the function removing the closure, and I put yours.I'm getting a warning on the init()          `init() {
        dm.filter(valoreSearhed: searchTerm, arrayTosearh: dm.airportVector) {
            self.filteredAirports = $0
        }
    }`

Comment: Do you know how to fix it? (I don’t have all you code dependencies, so can’t reproduce this warning.)

Comment: I think the issue my be is in the function of filtering, Xcode give the following warning..Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(valoreSearhed: String, arrayTosearh: [AirportModel], @escaping ([AirportModel]) -> ())'

Comment: I don't know why escaping, the filtering function don't have any closure ([AirportModel]) -> ()) is the simple as you wrote..

Comment: The second solution (after the edit) uses your original filter function, the one with the closure.

Comment: look like your part working, thanks, regarding the Init() is it on the View? I'm getting a warning say  Argument passed to call that takes no arguments...

Comment: Yes, it's `YourView.init()`.

Comment: I post here a link of my question, I've try many things without result, I've tried a new project with simply a list and the search function but still give me the warning,Argument passed to call that takes no arguments. I post the simple code of my ContentView, DatatManager and Model here..[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600719/swiftui-filter-array-via-searchbar] @Yonat

Comment: Ah, you simply need to add the `DataManager` argument to `init()` so it will be called: `init(dm: DataManager) { self.dm = dm; ... }`

Comment: Also, better wrap the assignment to your `@State` var in a dispatch to the main queue: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.filteredAirports = $0 }`

Comment: Ah.. sorry.. again.. i tried with the dm.. but give me the warning on the filtering function...Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter `struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm: DataManager
    @State private var searchTerm : String = ""
    @State var filteredAirports: [AirportModel] = []
    init(dataM: DataManager) {
        self.dm = dataM
        dm.filter(valoreSearhed: searchTerm, arrayTosearh: dm.airportVector, closure: {
            self.filteredAirports = $0
        })
    }

Comment: To silence this warning, You can add an explicit capture: `dm.filter( ..., closure: { [weak self] in self?.filteredAirports = $0 })`

Comment: Ah.. sorry sound hard the story.. I add the code.. new warning .. 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'ContentView'

Comment: ` init(dataM: DataManager) {
        self.dm = dataM
        dm.filter(valoreSearhed: searchTerm, arrayTosearh: dm.airportVector, closure: { [weak self] in self?.filteredAirports = $0 })
    }`

Comment: Probably better to put the filter call in a separate func, and call it from `onAppear` and also from the search bar. I put a complete file with working code at https://gist.github.com/yonat/e824402f85f909dfec54ddc3a0e46660 (easier than putting code in comments here).

Comment: Simple Suggestion, try to use `.hasPrefix` instance of `.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains` or `.contains` if the type of filtering does not matter